# How do you query a child and parent in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to figure out how to query to get a result that was either created by the current user or the current users parent.

I have two tables `users` and `workouts`. Both tables have a `created_by` column, which stores the user id of whoever created said user or workout record.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_by` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `users_created_by_foreign` (`created_by`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_created_by_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `workouts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_by` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `workouts_created_by_foreign` (`created_by`),
  CONSTRAINT `workouts_created_by_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
);
```

In my user model I have a function to return all the workouts that the user has created.

```
public function createdWorkouts(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Workout::class, 'created_by');
}
```

What I want to figure out is, how can I query to find a workout using a ID but only for workouts the current user has created or the creator of the current user has created. Below is my current route logic, which only returns a workout created by the current user.

```
$user = User::find(1); // This would come from the JWT
if (!$workout = $user->createdWorkouts()->find($args[‘workout_id’])) {
    return $response->withJson([], 404);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this instance, I probably wouldn't use an eloquent relationship as it could be either the users `id` or their `created_by` value.

Instead, I would change the method on your user model to read:

```
public function createdWorkouts()
{
    return Workout::where('created_by', $this->id)->orWhere('created_by', $this->created_by)->get();
}
```

Then you can do `$user->createdWorkouts()` which will return you a collection of all workouts where it was created by the user, or created by the user that created the user.

As it is a collection, you then have access to all of the other methods on a collection such as `find` etc